# p value and decision tree

Tags: decision-trees

let's say you create a GLM with y~x1+x2+x3. The p-value for x1 is 1% and x2 is 5% and x3 is 10%. Then, you know that beta for x1 and x2 are reliable, but not with x3. So, you can disregard x3's coefficient estimate and disregard as if x3 does not exist.

For creating a decision tree, although you cannot use p-values from the GLM above, if you create a decision tree with x1, x2, and x3, you can still have a good gut feeling that the root node will make a split using x1 and making a split using x3 will be highly unlikely.

I know there are not p-values in a decision tree but as long as you make a decision tree and GLM with the same predictors, then you can still have a good gut feeling that x1 may appear on the root node making a split because the p-value for x1 is the lowest. We cannot say firmly x1 is important in a decision tree just because x1's p-value in the GLM is the lowest. But, we are having a good gut feeling though.

That is what I am saying when I am comparing p-value with a decision tree.

Let me hear what your thoughts are. If you cannot have a good gut feeling which variables are dominant in a decision tree after making a GLM using the same predictors, let me know why.